# Arrays.sort from higher number to lower number?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

Basically I wanted to sort my arrays from *higher humbers* to *lowe numbers* using "Arrays.Sort". Sadly though I don't know how to sort it from higher to lower as "Arrays.sort" sorts those arrays from lower to higher.

Any suggestions?

Code:

```
    double sortArrays[] = {
        (float) probabilityOfFlush,
        (float) probabilityOfFullHouse,
        (float) probabilityOfOnePair,
        (float) probabilityOfPoker,
        (float) probabilityOfRoad,
        (float) probabilityOfRoyalFlush,
        (float) probabilityOfTriple,
        (float) probabilityOfTwoPairs
    };

    Arrays.sort (sortArrays);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortArrays));
```

Well, the output would be like this for an example:

> [0.0, 0.18018017709255219, 0.36036035418510437, 2.3423423767089844, 2.882882833480835, 2.882882833480835, 4.504504680633545, 45.76576614379883]

Comment: Check out the overloaded `sort` method. You'll need to use a `Double` array.

Comment: You can implement comparator for that

Comment: Why is this tagged [eclipse](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/eclipse/info)?

Comment: @Aroon I would use my [ReverseComparator](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/reverse-polarity.html) and [ComparableComparator](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/help-i-have-comparable-but-i-need.html).

Comment: You could move to a `Collection` and use `Collections.reverse()`.

Comment: Yea I am sorry for that, I searched for similiar post but couldn't find one.
After I posted mine I saw this one too :S

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Arrays.sort(array,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

As Bhesh points out below, you'll need to use a `Double[]` array instead of `double[]` as this will not work on primitive types.

Directly applied to your code:

```
Double[] sortArrays = {
    (Double) probabilityOfFlush,
    (Double) probabilityOfFullHouse, 
    (Double) probabilityOfOnePair, 
    (Double) probabilityOfPoker, 
    (Double) probabilityOfRoad, 
    (Double) probabilityOfRoyalFlush, 
    (Double) probabilityOfTriple, 
    (Double) probabilityOfTwoPairs
};

Arrays.sort(sortArrays, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortArrays));
```

I changed `double sortArrays[]` to `Double[] sortArrays`:

- The change in position of [] does not make a difference, but it is a matter of coding style/preference.
- The capital D in `Double` does however. This capital D makes use of the `Double` object type rather than the `double` primitive type.

You'll also need to add `import java.util.Collections;` to the top of your class file.  Since you mentioned you are using eclipse, you can hold ctrl+shift and press o to automatically take care of your imports by importing unimported classes, removing unused imports, and organizing imports by package.

Comment: +1, But you could add what Sotirios pointed in the comments, because OP has a `double[]` instead of `Double[]`.

Comment: @BheshGurung good catch, did not notice that.

Comment: Could you give me an Example with that Code I wrote in the Post? 
Sadly it doesnt work for me :S.
Thank you anyways!

Comment: @user3077388 Sure, give me a few minutes.

Comment: Lol deleted my Comment accidently, however it may intrest you so I thought I would tell you, I had to change float to (Double) because it couldn't convert it from float to Double, atleast that's what Eclipse told me ^^

Comment: @user3077388 woops, yeah that makes sense

Answer (score 2):

For a list

```
Collections.sort(list ,Collections.reverseOrder());
```

For an array

```
Arrays.sort(array, Collections.reverseOrder());
```

`Collections.reverseOrder()` Use a Comparator to inverse the natural order.

Note : It cannot sort arrays of primitives so you will need to convert your primitives to their respective objects. Integer for int, Double for double, Boolean for boolean, etc.

Example for usage

```
Double sortArrays[] = new Double[]{1.0,2.0,3.0,5.0,6.0};
Arrays.sort(sortArrays, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(sortArrays));
//output [6.0, 5.0, 3.0, 2.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep with primitives, you can sort your array and then reverse it. Note that you will have to use the [apache library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/ArrayUtils.html). This will run in `O(nlogn)`

```
Arrays.sort(array);
ArrayUtils.reverse(array);
```

If you don't want to use an exernal library, you can take the code :

```
public static void reverse(double[] array) {
            if (array == null) {
                return;
            }
            int i = 0;
            int j = array.length - 1;
            double tmp;
            while (j > i) {
                tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i];
                array[i] = tmp;
                j--;
                i++;
            }
 }
```

Comment: I could've used this one, but the code from turbo seemd to be easier!
But thank you anyways!

Comment: @user3077388 This solution requires 2 lines of code :P and you're dealing with primitive.

Comment: Well you know what I am dumb, I should've taken this one as it is simple, and it explains itself...

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using comparator

```
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<Double>()
{
    @Override
    public int compare(Double x, Double y)
    {
        return y - x;
    }
});
```

Using a comparator with y-x will sort highest to lowest, x - y will sort lowest to highest.